# Docker inside LXC starting container process caused "apply caps: operation not permitted"

Tags: docker, lxc, containers, virt-manager

I'm trying to run a Docker container inside an LXC container. 
However doing so causes me to get the following error: 

`[root@DH-DockerLXC01 alex]# docker run fedora bash
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:337: starting container process caused "apply caps: operation not permitted": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled`

I presume I need to set some configuration to be more permissive, but since I've created the LXC container with virt-manager I'm not sure where to start.

Note that the LXC container is using a chroot for storage, which AFAIK should allow docker to use full AUFS without any problems, but if I'm wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, LXC, by default, will not allow containers to have the CAP_MKNOD capability, as it could theoretically allow a container to take over a host. 
This can be overridden, but it's not very well documented. Based on a pull request from 2015 in a mailing list, I've been able to piece together a bit of XML that does it. You just have to edit the container definition, which is located in `/etc/libvirt/lxc/[container name]/`

```
<features>
  <capabilities policy='allow'>
    <mknod state='on'/>
  </capabilities>
</features>
```

Note that the file may already contain a  definition, in that case, paste the  section inside that section.
You may have to restart libvirt before it takes effect with `systemctl restart libvirtd.service` (this will not restart existing containers or VMs, only the service).

Answer (score 2):

For privileged LXC managed by Proxmox this solution helps:

```
lxc.apparmor.profile: unconfined
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow: a
lxc.cap.drop:
```

Take care about security!
Source: [Running Docker on Proxmox](https://danthesalmon.com/running-docker-on-proxmox/)

Answer (score 0):

J.F.Y.I.

- tl;dr: **Check the "Virtualization" settings in the BIOS**.

On my Proxmox machine, after upgrading the RAM, it turned out that this error occurred because the "Virtualization" setting in the BIOS had been "disabled" for some reason.

I turned it to "Enable" and started to work again. Dah.

- OS: Proxmox VE 7.4-4 (Debian GNU/Linux 11, bullseye)
- Motherboard: GA-880GM-USB3 Rev. 1.1